# Does the XWPF of Apache POI support paragraph's authohyphenation feature?

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I know, that HWPF has this feature, but I can't find any simular in XWPF.

Maybe there are workarounds for solving this problem. If you know some, please share with me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word Office OpenXML the automatic hyphenation settings are set for the whole document and may be suppressed for single paragraphs. The settings for the whole document are in `/word/settings.xml` part of the package. This is [XWPFSettings](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFSettings.html) but it is not possible to get this using the high level objects of `apache poi`  until now. So we need using low level objects and reflection to get this and having access to [CTSettings.addNewAutoHyphenation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTSettings.java#CTSettings.addNewAutoHyphenation%28%29).

The possible suppressing of automatic hyphenation for single paragraphs is done in [CTPPrBase.addNewSuppressAutoHyphens](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTPPrBase.java#CTPPrBase.addNewSuppressAutoHyphens%28%29) and is also not get-able using high level `apache poi`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSettings;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STSectionMark;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordAutoHyphenation {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  POIXMLDocumentPart part = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < document.getRelations().size(); i++) {
   part = document.getRelations().get(i);
   if (part instanceof XWPFSettings) break;
  }
  if (part instanceof XWPFSettings) {
   XWPFSettings settings = (XWPFSettings)part;
   Field _ctSettings = XWPFSettings.class.getDeclaredField("ctSettings"); 
   _ctSettings.setAccessible(true); 
   CTSettings ctSettings = (CTSettings)_ctSettings.get(settings);
   ctSettings.addNewAutoHyphenation();
  }

  String testtext = "This text tests whether automatic hyphenation opportunities are set on for this document and not are suppressed for this paragraph. Since in Word Office OpenXML the automatic hyphenation settings are set for the whole document and may be suppressed for single paragraphs.";

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setFontSize(18);
  run.getCTR().getRPr().addNewLang().setVal("en-US");
  run.setText(testtext);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addBreak(BreakType.COLUMN);

  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSuppressAutoHyphens();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setFontSize(18);
  run.getCTR().getRPr().addNewLang().setVal("en-US");
  run.setText(testtext);

  document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr().addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewCols().setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordAutoHyphenation.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks man, you saved me a few hours! Btw CTSettings contains a lot of other usable things, gonna dig into it.